# Cannot acces Tomcat Server from outside LAN network

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm seeking for some help with a Tomcat Server.

I got an OVH server ( Windows 2012 R2 ) with 2 networks interfaces :

- WAN ( 151.X.X.X )
- LAN ( 172.16.0.0 )

These two URLs work !

**http://172.16.0.6:8080/iComTest/servlet/conn

http://localhost:8080/iComTest/servlet/conn**

But I need to access throught **151.X.X.X/iComTest/servlet/conn** ! And it doesn't works !

My server.xml :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           address="0.0.0.0"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

**Furthermore, I set an inbound rule in the windows firewall allowing the port 8080 !**

When I do a nmap scan, I got this : **8080/tcp filtered http-proxy**

So I'm really confused.

I really appreciate some help on that topic !

Best regards,

Hugo

Comment: You might have more success asking on Super User or Server Fault.

Comment: Ok, thanks chrylis !

Comment: (To clarify: This question is on-topic here, but it seems to me it's probably something like a firewall configuration issue, and the other sites have more expertise about that topic.)